# What is the difference between this two Wordpress function?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

What is the difference between this two Wordpress function: 
`plugin_dir_url` vs `plugin_dir_path`.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return values of the Two mentioned functions

1. plugin_dir_path( **FILE** ) returns the servers filesystem directory path pointing to the current file, i.e. something along the lines of

> /home/www/your_site/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/includes/

This can be used for loading PHP files.

2. plugin_dir_url() behaves in a very similar fashion to plugins_url(). It also returns a web address, but with a trailing slash, i.e. something along the lines of

> http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/

This can be used to load images, stylesheets, JS and the like